# propel always select the default value of enum-columns?

Tags: php, mysql, propel

I'm quite irritated at unterstanding Propel's handling of enum-columns (using Propel 1.6.9 and MySQL). It seems that it always returns the default values.

The CREATE-Statement of the table:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `offerVariant` (
  `id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `offerID` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `name` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `description` text COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  [1] -> `amountType` enum('entity','person') COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT 'entity',
  `unitCount` smallint(5) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  [2] -> `priceType` enum('per night','per day','per hour','flat rate') COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT 'per night',
  `tax` tinyint(3) NOT NULL DEFAULT '7',
  `maxPrice` decimal(12,2) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0.00',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `offerID` (`offerID`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci AUTO_INCREMENT=5 ;
```

This is the relevant part of my schema.xml:

```
<table name="offerVariant">
        <column name="id" type="integer" required="true" primaryKey="true" autoIncrement="true"/>
        <column name="offerID" type="integer" size="11" required="true" />
        <column name="name" type="varchar" size="255" required="true" />
        <column name="description" type="longvarchar" required="true" />
        [1] -> <column name="amountType" type="enum" valueSet="entity, person" sqlType="ENUM('entity','person')" required="true" />
        <column name="unitCount" type="smallint" size="5" required="false" />
        [2] -> <column name="priceType" type="enum" valueSet="per night, per day, per hour, flat rate" sqlType="ENUM('per night','per day','per hour','flat rate')" required="true" />
        <column name="tax" type="tinyint" size="3" required="true" />
        <column name="maxPrice" type="decimal" size="14" required="true" />
        <foreign-key foreignTable="offer" refPhpName="offerVariant">
            <reference local="offerID" foreign="id"/>
        </foreign-key>
    </table>
```

I've got 2 enum-columns, *amountType* and *priceType*. 
I select 2 rows from this table

1. one with *amountType* == **entity** | *priceType* == **per night**
2. one with *amountType* == **person**| *priceType* == **per day**

The default value of *amountType* is **entity**, of *priceType* **per night**.

I fetch the rows this way:

```
public function selectVariantsByOffer($offerid){
    $variants = OffervariantQuery::create()
    ->filterByOfferId($offerid)
    ->find();

    return $variants;
}
```

and the return is:

```
[0] => Offervariant Object
  (
    [startCopy:protected] => 
    [id:protected] => 1
    [amounttype:protected] => 0
    [pricetype:protected] => 0
    [...]
  )

[1] => Offervariant Object
  (
    [startCopy:protected] => 
    [id:protected] => 2
    [amounttype:protected] => 0
    [pricetype:protected] => 0
    [...]
  )
```

after using the getters:

> ```
> [0] => Array
>     (
>         [id] => 1
>         [...]
>         [amountType] => entity
>         [priceType] => per night
>     )
>
> [1] => Array
>     (
>         [id] => 2
>         [...]
>         [amountType] => entity
>         [priceType] => per night
>     )
> ```

simply wrong.

I read about the fact that Propel interprets the type="enum" another way than MySQL does, and that it would be nessecary to set the sqlType in the schema.xml. I did this as mentioned above, rebuilt, but no change.

1. Isn't it possible to fetch the stated enum-value?
2. Or is my schema.xml incorrect?
3. Or do I fetch the wrong way?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> **ENUM Columns**
>
> Although stored in the database as **integers**, ENUM columns let users manipulate a set of predefined values, without worrying about their storage. [http://propelorm.org](http://propelorm.org/cookbook/working-with-advanced-column-types.html#enum-columns)

If you set your column in propel as `ENUM`, declare in sql as `INTEGER`.

Or, preferably, you can try `type="VARCHAR" sqlType="ENUM('...')"`.

Comment: I did it the varchar-way and it works like a charm. Thank you!

Comment: yup, this is definitely works.. I use that varchar solution too

Comment: Just did the same w/ `text` field, `type="VARCHAR" sqlType="TEXT"`, as I did not want to treat the text field like an array in PHP.